# form is submitimg even I am using return false

Tags: jquery

form is submitimg even I am calling return false 
my code

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('.submit').click(function() {
        $('.hour').each(function() {
            var $hours = $(this).val();
            if ($hours == "") {
                alert(" Active Time is required");
                return true;
            }
        });
    });
});​
```

submit button

```
 <input type="submit" class="submit" name="Submit" id="Submit" value="Submit" 
onclick="return validateForm();"/>
```

Comment: You have the `return` statement instead the `.each` callback (lets assume it was `return false;`). It has no influence on the return value of the event handler.

Comment: I do not see any `return false` in your code. You even do not have any return from `.submit` click handler.

Answer (score 1):

You need to return outside the `.each` callback function.

Answer (score 0):

```
$('.submit').click(function() {
var r = false;
 $('.hour').each(function() {
            var $hours = $(this).val();
            if ($hours == "") {
                alert(" Active Time is required");
                r = true;
            }
        });
return r;
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You are not returning anything from the click event handler bound to the submit button. You can significantly shorten your code by using the `.filter()` method to reduce the set of `.hour` elements to those with no value, and you can return the result of a check of the length of the resulting set of elements from the event handler to allow/prevent form submission:

```
$(".submit").click(function () {
    // This return statement returns from the click event handler
    return $(".hour").filter(function () {
        // This one returns from the filter callback (once for each element)
        return this.value === "";
    }).length === 0;
});​
```

Here's a [working example](http://jsfiddle.net/jamesallardice/APyE7/).

Answer (score 0):

```
<script>

    $(document).ready(function(){
        $('.submit').click(function(e){ 
    var flag = false;
            $('.hour').each(function() {
                var $hours =  $(this).val();
                if (!flag && $hours == "")
                {
                    flag = true;
                    alert(" Active Time is required"); 
                    e.preventDefault();
                } 
            });   
        });
    });

</script>
```

Submit Button

```
<input type="submit" class="submit" name="Submit" id="Submit" value="Submit" />
```